# Tabela não atualiza corretamente após edição

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho uma `dataTable` e na ultima coluna tenho um botão de editar que abre um `dialog` com um campo pra ser preenchido. Quando clico em editar a tabela é atualizada com os dados editados, porém se eu dou um F5 os dados antigos voltam a aparece na `dataTable`.

Método editar no bean:

```
public void pausarTarefa(){
        System.err.println("Pausar");
        try {
            tarefa.setStatus("Pausado");
            tarefa.setDataFim(new Date());

            TarefaDAO tarefaDAO = new TarefaDAO();
            tarefaDAO.editar(tarefa);   
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgInfo("Tarefa Pausada com Sucesso");
            tarefa = new Tarefa();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao Pausar Tarefa");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Método que preenche a lista usada no dataTable:

```
@PostConstruct
public void listar() {
    listaTarefa = new ArrayList<>();
    System.err.println("Metodo Listar");
    try {
        TarefaDAO tarefaDAO = new TarefaDAO();
        listaTarefa = tarefaDAO.listarPorUsuario(usuarioBean
                .getUsuarioLogado());

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao listar tarefas: "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

O escopo do bean é `ViewScoped`.
No banco de dados os dados ficam corretos após a edição, é só a dataTable que traz os dados antigos. Alguém pode ajudar?

---

DataTable:

```
p:dataTable value="#{tarefaBean.listaTarefa}" id="tarefaTable"
                var="tarefa" style="margin-top: 20px"
                emptyMessage="Nenhuma Tarefa Encontrada. " rows="10"
                paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                paginatorPosition="botton">
```

Comment: Poste o código de sua dataTable(só a declaração dela).

Comment: Editei a pergunta com o código

Answer (score 1):

Vou explicar o que esta acontecendo. Primeiro sua `dataTable` está chamando a `listaTarefa` porém quando você chamo o método `pausarTarefa()` você não esta atualizando sua `listaTarefa` e sua `dataTable`.

Oque você pode fazer para resolver seu problema:
dentro do método `pausarTarefa()` chamar o método `listar()`, assim sua lista vai estar atualizada. Bem agora por ultimo você precisa atualizar sua `dataTable`, use o update do botão(`update="tarefaTable"`) ou um `<p:ajax>` qualquer.

**Edit:**

altere seu método, remova o `@PostConstruct`:

```
 public List<Tarefa> listar() {
        List<Tarefa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        System.err.println("Metodo Listar");
        try {
            TarefaDAO tarefaDAO = new TarefaDAO();
            lista = tarefaDAO.listarPorUsuario(usuarioBean.getUsuarioLogado());
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            FacesUtil.adicionarMsgErro("Erro ao listar tarefas: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

e altere sua `dataTable`:

```
p:dataTable value="#{tarefaBean.listar}" id="tarefaTable"
                var="tarefa" style="margin-top: 20px"
                emptyMessage="Nenhuma Tarefa Encontrada. " rows="10"
                paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                paginatorPosition="botton">
```

Comment: Eu estava chamando o método listar no <f:event> no começo da página. Fiz o que voce disse a tabela atualiza, porem quando dou um F5 volta tudo como era. Vou fazer um vídeo pra te mostra para que você possa entender melhor

Comment: De uma olhada no video para compreender melhor o que acontece: https://youtu.be/yeA5yYqOszw

Comment: editei minha resposta.

Comment: Funciona, porém continua voltando ao estado anterior após o F5. Quer que eu compartilhe o projeto com voce pelo GitHub?

Comment: Agora estou no serviço, você tem certeza que sua tarefa foi atualizada no banco de dados?e tente limpar também o cache do seu navegador

Comment: Tenho sim. Eu entro no banco e está atualizado, Já tentei limpar o cache e até entrar anônimo no navegador e nada..

Comment: Será que pode ser a minha NamedQuery? `@NamedQuery(name = "Tarefa.listarPorCodigo", query = "SELECT tarefa FROM Tarefa tarefa WHERE tarefa.usuario = :usuario"),`

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido. Conversando com um amigo descobri que as consultas também tem que ser comitadas. Então minha consulta no DAO ficou dessa forma:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      public List<Tarefa> listarPorUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
       Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
       Transaction transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();

       List<Tarefa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
       try {
        Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Tarefa.listarPorCodigo");
        consulta.setParameter("usuario", usuario);
        lista = consulta.list();
        System.err.println("LISTA no DAO: "+lista);
        transacao.commit();
       } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        throw ex;
       } finally {
        sessao.close();
       }
       return lista;
      }
```